# How can I build a function to create a new column based on other columns containing a certain string?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have a dataframe with some clubs and their nationality. Just like this one:

[image]

I created a function that I will use to create a new column based on the Nationality. I tested and it works fine if I want to find values that are equal. However, I needed to search for strings that **contains** a certain character. E.g.: If the string contains 'Br' than I want to create a new column which will receive a certain value. If contains another string, than it will receive another value.

This is what I've done so far (and it is working fine, but I needed something like a 'contains'):

```
# Function 
def label_race (row):
    if row['Nationality'] == 'Brazil':
        return 'Brasil'
    else:
        return 'NA'

df.apply (lambda row: label_race(row), axis=1)
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
# Function 
def label_race (row):
    if row['Nationality'] contains'Br':
        return 'Brasil'
    if row['Nationality'] contains'Brl':
        return 'Brasil2'
    else:
return 'NA'

df.apply (lambda row: label_race(row), axis=1)
```

I found some tips, but most of them use things like is.find() or df[].str.contains. And I couldn't adapt to what I want.

Comment: OK, can you please give us an example of data that would require a contains solution?

Comment: Specifically, this line: "_E.g.: If the string contains 'Br' than I want to create a new column which will receive a certain value._" is very vague.

Comment: hey @cs95 can you check if the question is ok now? Tks

Comment: It makes sense but the simplest way to do this is via regex and I don't think pandas can do this easily. I tried `s = pd.Series(['Brasssseeel', 'I like Brl'])` as an example using the "Br" and "Brl" as the search patterns. Couldn't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wanted to create a new column with binary values (if condition met then A else B), you could do something like this

```
#create a column 'new' with value 'Brasil' if 'Nationality' value contains 'Bra', else put 'NA'
df['new'] = df['Nationality'].apply(lambda x: 'Brasil' if 'Bra' in x else 'NA')
```

otherwise, if you wanted to create a column and use multiple rules in the same column, you could do something like this...

```
#create a column 'new' and insert value 'ARG' whenever 'Nationality' contains 'Arg', 
df.loc[df['Nationality'].str.contains('Arg'), 'new'] = 'ARG'
#and 'BRA' whenever Nationality contains 'Brazil', without overriding any other values
df.loc[df['Nationality'].str.contains('Brazil'), 'new'] = 'BRA'
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can make do with `str.extract` and `dot`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Nationality': ['Brazil', 'abBrl', 'abcd', 'BrX']})

new_df = df.Nationality.str.extract('(?P<Brazil2>Brl)|(?P<Brazil>Br)')

new_df.notnull().dot(new_df.columns)
```

Output:

```
0     Brazil
1    Brazil2
2           
3     Brazil
dtype: object
```